# Migrate from MariaDB to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, migration

We would like to migrate an application in our company system. The application uses MariaDB and in the companywe uses MySQL. What should I consider in the process, especially if we are using MySQL 8 (I don't have the information yet). I have read, that it is not (easy) possible to migrate back from MySQL 8 to an older version or to MariaDB. But what is the case if you try to move from MariaDB to MySQL (maybe MySQL 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB is a fork of MySQL, and thus they're largely cross-compatible. Normal queries (INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT) should be largely unaffected. Where you get into trouble is the more exotic stuff.

If they're using Aria or any of the other exotic table formats MariaDB provides, you'll need to convert those - probably to InnoDB.

I have moved sites in the other direction many times and never hit a major snag that I can recall.

They've got some good documentation here, For the most part you should be able to understand the reverse direction.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/moving-from-mysql/

Lastly, if you haven't tried MariaDB, I'd suggest giving it a try. It's very similar to MySQL and has the original developers of MySQL behind it post-Oracle-buyout. Arguably better licensing terms and performance. It's worth a look.